# Scala DynamicVariable's replacement of ThreadLocal

Tags: java, scala, thread-local

I don't understand the code and logic behind `DynamicVariable`:

- First you create a `DynamicVariable` instance with a default value ... a default value??? you want a value per thread! does this mean you have the same default shared across potentially all threads? defeats the purpose ... or?
- Then I see in all examples the `withValue` pretty much looks like creating a new instance each time, or?

e.g. `ThreadLocal` with a classic case that makes sense `SimpleDateFormat` that is very expensive to create each time and it is not thread-safe:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormatTl = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>();
...
// many threads execute this, check if there already exists a 
// Thread-bound instance otherwise create a new one per-thread
if (dateFormatTl.get() == null) {
  dateFormatTl.set(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"));
}
// safely use the Thread-bound instance
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = dateFormatTl.get();
dateFormat.format(new Date(java.util.Date.getTime()));
```

How can I replicate the same functionality of above but in Scala and using `DynamicVariable`?

```
// create with default instance ... 
// what for? I don't want the same instance shared across all Threads!
val dateFormatDv = new DynamicVariable[SimpleDateFormat](new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"))

// many threads execute this ... 
// I see it is creating one new instance each time, and 
// that is not what I want
 dateFormatDv.withValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss")) {
   // safely use the Thread-bound instance, but this is a new one each time arrrggggg
   dateFormatDv.value.format(new Date(java.util.Date.getTime()))
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done like this:

```
  Future {
    dateFormatDv.withValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss")) {
      doStuffWithDateFormat(dateFormatDv.value)
      doMoreStuffWithTheSameFormatInstance(dateFormatDv.value)
    }          
  }

  Future {
    dateFormatDv.withValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss")) {
      useADifferentInstanceOfDateFormat(dateFormat.value)
    }
  }
```

As for the default value, it just lets you set it so that you can use it conveniently in the current thread without `.withValue`

```
 doSomethingWithDefaultFormatInstance(dateFormat.value)
```

Comment: You mean that if the same thread executes the line `dateFormatDv.withValue` more than once, only one instance of the `SimpleDateFormat` is created the first time and reused in each subsequent execution?

Comment: No, I mean, that you execute `.withValue` once, and then everything within that block sees that value.

Comment: but that's the whole point, you have many incoming threads executing `.withValue` and above and the whole point of `ThreadLocal` is to have a reusable separate instance per thread, and not just create a new instance each time. So this code you wrote is not 100% the same to what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, many threads are doing `.withValue(new Foo) { ... }`, and each has it's own instance `Foo` inside the `{}`. That's exactly what you describe

Comment: Ah ok ... I need to test it to be sure :) but I am accepting for now ...

Answer (score 0):

A `ThreadLocal`ification of Scala's `DynamicVariable` would be more like this I guess:

```
// do only once and put in static scope within some Object
val dateFormatDv = new DynamicVariable[Option[SimpleDateFormat]](None)

// this is executed by different threads
def formatTimestamp(timestamp: Long): String = {
  dateFormatDv.value match {
    case None => dateFormatDv.value_=(Some(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss")))
  }
  // safely use the Thread-bound instance
  dateFormatDv.value.map(_.format(new Date(timestamp))).get
}
```

Comment: yes, it's the same as `.withValue`, just less idiomatic.
You could also just use `ThreadLocal` instead.